# pandas iterrows throwing error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a change data capture on two dataframes. The logic is to merge two dataframes and group by one keys and then run a loop for groups having count >1 to see which column 'updated'. I am getting strange error. any help is appreciated.
code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print("reading wolverine xlxs")


# defining metadata

df_header = ['DisplayName','StoreLanguage','Territory','WorkType','EntryType','TitleInternalAlias',
         'TitleDisplayUnlimited','LocalizationType','LicenseType','LicenseRightsDescription',
         'FormatProfile','Start','End','PriceType','PriceValue','SRP','Description',
         'OtherTerms','OtherInstructions','ContentID','ProductID','EncodeID','AvailID',
         'Metadata', 'AltID', 'SuppressionLiftDate','SpecialPreOrderFulfillDate','ReleaseYear','ReleaseHistoryOriginal','ReleaseHistoryPhysicalHV',
          'ExceptionFlag','RatingSystem','RatingValue','RatingReason','RentalDuration','WatchDuration','CaptionIncluded','CaptionExemption','Any','ContractID',
          'ServiceProvider','TotalRunTime','HoldbackLanguage','HoldbackExclusionLanguage']
df_w01 = pd.read_excel("wolverine_1.xlsx", names = df_header)

df_w02 = pd.read_excel("wolverine_2.xlsx", names = df_header)

df_w01['version'] = 'OLD'
df_w02['version'] = 'NEW'

#print(df_w01)
df_m_d = pd.concat([df_w01, df_w02], ignore_index = True)

first_pass = df_m_d[df_m_d.duplicated(['StoreLanguage','Territory','TitleInternalAlias','LocalizationType','LicenseType','FormatProfile'], keep=False)]

first_pass_keep_duplicate = df_m_d[df_m_d.duplicated(['StoreLanguage','Territory','TitleInternalAlias','LocalizationType','LicenseType','FormatProfile'], keep='first')]

group_by_1 = first_pass.groupby(['StoreLanguage','Territory','TitleInternalAlias','LocalizationType','LicenseType','FormatProfile'])
for i,rows in group_by_1.iterrows():
    print("rownumber", i)
    print (rows)


print(first_pass)
```

And The error I get :

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iterrows' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The resulf of a group_by operation is a group, not a dataframe. A group does not contain rows to iterate; rather, it contains dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GroupBy` object supports iteration, so instead of

```
for i,rows in group_by_1.iterrows():
    print("rownumber", i)
    print (rows)
```

you need to do something like

```
for name, group in group_by_1:
    print name
    print group
```

then you can do what you need to do with each `group`

See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do as suggested and use `apply`? Something like:

```
def print_rows(rows):
    print rows

group_by_1.apply(print_rows)
```

Comment: The actual problem is not to print rows but how to access each rows within a group and try to do a list /for-loop kind of operation. I overcame this group issue by using below but stuck with a problem where I can not 'REINDEX' rows to run an inner for loop as shown below   :    for i,rows in group_by_1:
    rows.reset_index()
    rows.reindex(index=range(0,len(rows)))
    print(rows)
    for j in range(len(rows)-1):
        print(j)
        print(rows.loc[j,:])

Comment: Problem is no matter what I try it is keeping the original rownumber from the spreadsheet/dataframe and not allowing me to run an inner for loop failing saying :KeyError: 'the label [2] is not in the [index]'

Comment: The print was just an example based on your code. The issue at hand was accessing iterrows for which I gave an alternative using apply. If you're facing a different issue then I suggest you update your question or start a new one.